# Apply padding and write text in a video using single ffmpeg command

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I want to apply padding on the top of a video and write text on padded area using a single ffmpeg command. 
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic syntax of required command is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf pad=iw:ih+100:0:100:black,drawtext=text='Hello World':fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=40:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(100-th)/2 out.mp4
```

In this command, first a black padding of 100 pixels is added at the top, then text is placed centered within the padded area, See syntax for color [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color).